# Is it possible to bundle the javascript source in a react-native module

Tags: react-native

I am trying to bundle the JS for consumption by host react-native applications. I want to change the package.json `main` property to point to a bundled javascript file instead of the `index` file. Is this possible?

Comment: Why? Are you building a library?

Comment: @Kai yes a library to be consumed by other react-native apps.

Comment: It should automatically be bundled when it's built. I don't think this is necessary